# iOS Project Build Problems

Tags: ios

My project, in iPhone5s simulator running above normal, but iPhone5 compile error, an error message is as follows:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/apple/Desktop/……/UMSocial_Sdk_3.3.7'

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/apple/Desktop/……_SDK/lib/libP2P_device.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/apple/Desktop/……_SDK/lib/libP2P_device.a (2 slices)

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/apple/Desktop/……/UMAnalytics_Sdk/libMobClickLibrary_armv6.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/apple/Desktop/……_Sdk/libMobClickLibrary_armv6.a

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/apple/Desktop/……_iOS_SDK/lib/libP2P.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/apple/Desktop/……2P.a
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InterfaceJump", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in CommonFunc.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Your project link some file didn't support i386 architecture. Maybe this file ??just support arm architecture.
>
> You should make sure your "Build Settings" -> "Valid Architectures" didn't contain i386. iPhone5's architecture is "armv7", it shouldn't compile for architecture i386.
>
> If your just want to build target phone architecture, you can set "Build Active Architecture Only" to YES.

I sorry, I think your iPhone5 is device, you can try to change "Valid Architecture" to only support 64bit or 32bit arm architecture, and change "Build Active Architecture Only" to have a try.

iPhone5 simulator is build fine, and iPhone5s build failed usually is arm64 problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed a project some files do not support i386 architecture, very grateful.